# scrbook twoside=off but alternating headings like with twoside=on?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, double-sided

I use `scrbook` for a large document and decided to print it out one sided only. So I added `twoside=off` to the `scrbook` class options.

However, that's not quite what I wanted to achieve. There is only a non-altenating header now and header and pagenumbers are centered.

How do I get alternating headers (chapter title on even, section title on odd pages) and headers and footers aligned to the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `twoside=semi`:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\clearscrheadfoot
\rohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{\rightmark}
\refoot{\pagemark}
\rofoot{\pagemark}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Or you can use non robust test:

```
\documentclass[twoside=off]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\ifodd\value{page} \rightmark\else\leftmark\fi}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. I chose the twoside=semi solution, as I think the layout of the page margins looks better this way.